# Facing problem with : Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN" and Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: html, d3.js, bar-chart

I am new in d3.js and right now trying to visualize a csv in a barchart. But facing an error like this : Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN" and Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN". My full code is below: need expert advice.

The csv data looks like as following :
year,value
AK,35
AK,55
AL,165
AL,323
AR,86
AR,155
AZ,409
AZ,719
CA,1891
CA,3390
CO,292
CO,442
CT,117
CT,220
DE,392
DE,1819
FL,1064
FL,1870
GA,423
GA,728
HI,53
HI,108
IA,75
IA,173
ID,62
ID,102
IL,551
IL,858
IN,529
IN,901
KS,102
KS,206
KY,162
KY,251
LA,255
LA,684
MA,350
MA,621
MD,244
MD,439
ME,71
ME,125
MI,353
MI,607
MN,221
MN,392
MO,184

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>`enter code here`
        .bar {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .highlight {
            fill: orange;
        }
</style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="600" height="500"></svg>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = 200,
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin;

    svg.append("text")
       .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
       .attr("x", 50)
       .attr("y", 50)
       .attr("font-size", "24px")
       .text("Polarity visualization of csv data")

    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.4),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");

    d3.csv("polarity.csv", function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        g.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
         .append("text")
         .attr("y", height - 250)
         .attr("x", width - 100)
         .attr("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("stroke", "black")
         .text("Year");

        g.append("g")
         .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d){
             return "$" + d;
         }).ticks(10))
         .append("text")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
         .attr("y", 6)
         .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
         .attr("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("stroke", "black")
         .text("Stock Price");

        g.selectAll(".bar")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("class", "bar")
         .on("mouseover", onMouseOver) //Add listener for the mouseover event
         .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)   //Add listener for the mouseout event
         .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
         .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
         .transition()
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .duration(400)
         .delay(function (d, i) {
             return i * 50;
         })
         .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
    });
    
    //mouseover event handler function
    function onMouseOver(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'highlight');
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()     // adds animation
          .duration(400)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth() + 5)
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) - 10; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value) + 10; });

        g.append("text")
         .attr('class', 'val') 
         .attr('x', function() {
             return x(d.year);
         })
         .attr('y', function() {
             return y(d.value) - 15;
         })
         .text(function() {
             return [ '$' +d.value];  // Value of the text
         });
    }

    //mouseout event handler function
    function onMouseOut(d, i) {
        // use the text label class to remove label on mouseout
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()     // adds animation
          .duration(400)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

        d3.selectAll('.val')
          .remove()
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in d3.js and right now trying to visualize a csv in a barchart. But facing an error like this : Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN" and Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN". My full code is below: need expert advice.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an example of data from `polarity.csv`.

Comment: Print to console the data you get from the call  d3.csv("polarity.csv", function(error, data) { ...  console.log(data) ... Make sure every object in the 'data' is valid

Comment: Hi Yakov, The CSV data looks like following :   year,value
AK,35
AK,55
AL,165
AL,323
AR,86
AR,155
AZ,409
AZ,719
CA,1891
CA,3390
CO,292
CO,442
CT,117
CT,220
DE,392
DE,1819
FL,1064
FL,1870
GA,423
GA,728
HI,53
HI,108
IA,75
IA,173
ID,62
ID,102
IL,551
IL,858
IN,529
IN,901
KS,102
KS,206
KY,162
KY,251
LA,255
LA,684
MA,350
MA,621
MD,244
MD,439
ME,71
ME,125
MI,353
MI,607
MN,221
MN,392
MO,184

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there is no type conversion, which makes every attribute in the data a string. Since every number is a string, you can't pass it to `d3.max()` or `scale.range()`, hence the errors.

To convert the type in d3.v4, you can use the second argument of `d3.csv()`. It is a function that maps each row of the CSV to another object before sending the data to the callback.

Let's add the second argument.

Currently, you have:

```js
d3.csv("polarity.csv", function(error, data) {...})
```

Which is equivalent to:

```js
d3.csv("polarity.csv", (d) => (d), function(error, data) {...})
```

The code above is equivalent because the second argument is just an identity function. Before calling the last callback, `d3.csv()` is taking every row and returning it without any change.

Going a step further, the same code is also equivalent to this one:

```js
d3.csv("polarity.csv", (d) => ({... d}), function(error, data) {...})
```

The code above is equivalent because the `{...d}` is just [ES6 object destructuring notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). The `d3.csv()` is still taking every row and returning it without any change.

Up until now, we just changed the notation without making any change in the data. Now it's the time to do the type conversions. If you know that `d.value` is a number, you can overwrite it and coerce the type:

```js
d3.csv("polarity.csv", (d) => ({... d, value: +d.value}), function(error, data) {...})
```

The `value: +d.value` means that we are taking the `d.value` string, converting it to a number, and assigning it back to the `value` property.

Now the second argument is doing the adequate type conversions, and the `data` in the third callback will have `d.value` as a number, which will be compatible with `d3.max()` and `scale.range()`

#### Side Note:

This process was made easier in d3.v5 with the introduction with `d3.autoType()` and the use of Promises in `d3.csv()`. If you're learning D3 concepts in general, and you're not tied to d3.v4 for a specific project, I highly recommend reading about [the changes between v4 and v5](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) (which are only a handful) and about [the use of `d3.autoType()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-autotype).

Comment: It is now solved. Thanks for all the suggestions.